# Extract Base64 string from an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am sending a `base64 string` to my `node.js` server. But its adding the string inside object brackets `{}`

**Front-end code:**

I `encode` the base64 string to preserve it.

```
  let options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
     };

let encodedImage = encodeURIComponent(body);

return this._http.put<IUser>(`${BASE_URL}/api/users/${id}/photo`, encodedImage, options)
  .map(data => {
    return data;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // do whatever you want when error occurs
    console.log(err);

    // re-throw error so you can catch it when subscribing, fallback to generic error code
    return Observable.throw(err || 'API_ERROR');
  });
```

}

**Serverside:**

```
let upload = (req, res) => {

 let b64string = req.body;
 console.log(b64string);

}
```

**The console log is:**

```
{ 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA.....+idkVe3H/9k=': '' }
```

How can I extract the `base64` string from within the object so I can access it. it seems like a simple thing but my brain has given up. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

[image]

**Update 2:**

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: Check in the network tab if the request is actual `x-www-form-urlencoded` and check if you are using a body-parser in your node server that transforms the `req.body` to json

Comment: @alex-rokabilis its yes to both. Im using `body-parser` in node and the request is `x-www-form-urlencoded` (please see updated question).

Comment: So it must be the `body-parser`. Please post the code you declare it, something like `app.use(bodyParser.......)`

Comment: @alex-rokabilis please see my update on the question.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something putting your string in an JSON encoded value, hence the {'...' : '...'}.
You could put the base64 encoded string in an json object from the get go, that way you have an expected input when you get the object. You just need to get the string from the json key.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you creating a `PUT` request with

`Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but you pass a single string as your data. So the `body-parser` sees this string as a `key` with an empty `value` and that's why you get this console log.

So the solution to this,

```js
let options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
};

let requestBody = new URLSearchParams()

requestBody.append('encodedImage',body)


return this._http.put < IUser > (`${BASE_URL}/api/users/${id}/photo`, requestBody, options)
```

So we said we have a content type of `form-urlencoded` (that means all of your data will be passed as giant url query) and we passed a urlencoded form (through the URLSearchParams)

Please bear in mind [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) browser compatibility.

Please consider using `multipart/form-data` for your file uploads instead, if you don't have any limitations. The logic of the above will be the same except the `new URLSearchParams()` will be `new FormData()`.